# Not returning user array inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

I am trying to return what Chinese zodiac after the date inputs have been entered. 
I am a bit stuck on what part of my code is not returning values properly.

I have tried multiple alert and console.log commands to return the values as well as changing different methods and code layout.  Here’s the code.

```js
var start = 1901

var chineseZodiac {

  var birthYears {

    //Creates Inputs for the date.
    var birthDate = parseInt(prompt('Enter the date of birth as an integer, ranging from 1 to 31', '31'));
    var birthMonth = parseInt(prompt('Enter the month of birth as an integer, ranging from 1 to 12', '12'));
    var birthYear = parseInt(prompt('Enter the year of birth as a 4 digit integer', '2016'));
    var birthingTime = new Date(birthDate, birthMonth, birthYear);

    //Collecting data on the current time and stores the user inputs
    var currentTime = new Date();
    currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
    currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth();
    currentDay = currentTime.getDate();

    //Declares Array of chineseZodiak
    var zodiacSigns = ["Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Goat", "Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig"];
  }
  resultTest(alert(resultSaving));

  //reporting function

}


function resultTest() {
  var resultSaving = math.floor(zodiacSigns[(birthYear - start) % 12]);
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = resultSaving;
}

console.log(math.floor(zodiacSigns([birthYear - start] % 12)));
```

Comment: this does not look like valid JavaScript. You should be seeing a syntax error in your console (there are several, in fact). if you'd been looking for the result of console.log commands, did you not spot this?

Answer (score 1):

Your post is not valid JavaScript, there are a few things that need to be corrected.

Here is an example of how to get the expected result.

```js
/**
 * Put the main logic into a function.
 */
function getZodiacSign () {

  const start = 1901,
    zodiacSigns = ['Rat', 'Ox', 'Tiger', 'Rabbit', 'Dragon', 'Snake', 'Horse', 'Goat', 'Monkey', 'Rooster', 'Dog', 'Pig'];

  let birthYear = getUserBirthYear();
  const index = (birthYear - start) % 12;
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
    'Congratulations, you are a <strong>' + zodiacSigns[index] + '</strong> on the Chinese Zodiac';

}

/**
 * Use a prompt to get user birth year.
 *
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getUserBirthYear() {
  return parseInt(prompt('Enter the year of birth as a 4 digit integer', '2016'));
}

// Call the function
getZodiacSign();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

The way you are trying to define variables is not valid:

```
var chineseZodiac {
  ...
}
```

You are prompting the user three times for information that you don't even use later, it would be much better to use a form input to collect the information, and definitely, do not make the user enter information you are not going to use later.

```
// Get rid of these lines
var birthDate = parseInt(prompt('Enter the date of birth as an integer, ranging from 1 to 31', '31'));
var birthMonth = parseInt(prompt('Enter the month of birth as an integer, ranging from 1 to 12', '12'));
var birthingTime = new Date(birthDate, birthMonth, birthYear);
```

It doesn't look like you are using the current date anywhere, you can get rid of these lines as well.

```
//Collecting data on the current time and stores the user inputs
var currentTime = new Date();
currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth();
currentDay = currentTime.getDate();
```

You are calling `math.floor()` on a string

```
math.floor(zodiacSigns[(birthYear - start) % 12]);
```

Instead, use the `index` calculated to get the corresponding array element.

Consider substituting prompts with form inputs and alerts with displaying results in the page.

Comment: thanks dude ive looked back over it, seen a few problems throughout it. thank you for the impput

Comment: @JoeyMercer did the answer solve your problem? If so, please, mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors.

You can try with something like this

```
var start = 1901

var chineseZodiac = function() {
  var birthYears 
  {

    //Creates Inputs for the date.
    var birthDate = parseInt(prompt('Enter the date of birth as an integer, ranging from 1 to 31', '31'));
    var birthMonth = parseInt(prompt('Enter the month of birth as an integer, ranging from 1 to 12', '12'));
    var birthYear = parseInt(prompt('Enter the year of birth as a 4 digit integer', '2016'));
    var birthingTime = new Date(birthDate, birthMonth, birthYear);

    //Collecting data on the current time and stores the user inputs
    var currentTime = new Date();
    currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
    currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth();
    currentDay = currentTime.getDate();

    //Declares Array of chineseZodiak
    var zodiacSigns = ["Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Goat", "Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig"];
  }

resultTest(birthYear)

function resultTest(birthYear)
{
  var resultSaving = zodiacSigns[Math.floor((birthYear-start) % 12)];
  console.log(resultSaving)
}

}

console.log(start)

chineseZodiac()
```